# Renaming several .txt files consistently in R

Tags: r

I have uploaded a lof of text files into R that are written in the following format:

```
building_01.txt
building_01_window_01_roof_01.txt
building_01_window_01_roof_01.txt
building_02_window_02.txt
...
```

I would like to remove the numbers following each of the words, so that the final files read:

```
building.txt
building_window_roof.txt
building_window_roof.txt
...
```

Reading previous posts, I tried to use file.rename to get rid of the numbers after "building"

```
files_list <- list.files(pattern="building_[01-80].txt")

file.rename(files_list, paste0("building_",".txt"))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in file.rename(list.files(pattern = "building_[01-80]"), paste0("building_",  : 
'from' and 'to' are of different lengths`
```

The numbers after "building" do not go beyond 80, so I am sure the selection above includes all files in the directory. Also, I don't want to lose any of the "window" or "roof" labels in the file, just get rid of the numbers after the label. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Hope this makes sense. As you can see, I am new to R and any help would be really appreciated :)

Comment: What about duplicate filenames? If you rename a file to another, it would most likely overwrite the previous (or at least throw an error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy. The package you want to use is **stringr** and the function is `str_remove_all()`.

```
library(stringr)
listoffiles = c( "building.txt", 
                 "building_window_roof.txt",
                 "building_window_roof.txt" 
                 )
cleanedfiles = str_remove_all( listoffiles, "\\d+" )
> cleanedfiles
[1] "building.txt"             "building_window_roof.txt" "building_window_roof.txt"
```

Comment: I see that every file had also an ID number in the file name (e.g. building_**0023**.txt) which also gets lost with str_remove_all. Is there a way to delete all numbers except from the ID numbers?. Cheers

Comment: You can build a [regex](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html) to work your way to the final result. `str_remove_all()` with that specification just removes every digit.